# Select data from two rows of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called TransferRequest with two columns that are (receivingPrison, currentPrison). They both reference a table Prison with columns (prisonID, location). 
I need to have some sort of join to display the 'location' of both prison eg. Result: "Washington", "New York".
I know to get the location from one table I can do:

```
SELECT Prison.location  
FROM Prison
JOIN TransferRequest
ON Prison.prisonID = TransferRequest.currentPrison;
```

And:

```
SELECT Prison.location  
FROM Prison
JOIN TransferRequest
ON Prison.prisonID = TransferRequest.receivingPrison;
```

But I'm not sure how to do a SELECT for two of the same type of items from the same type of table. What would I do to get this table? (Headers: Current Location, Receiving Location).

Comment: what do you mean by *display the 'location' of both prison* ? what are the *both prisons* ?

Comment: right now the TransferRequest table has two columns rP, and cP. They have ids that both reference the table prison, so like
(rp,cp): (1,3),(2,4),(5,1).
And Prison has the ids, with another column that has the location
(prisonID,location): (1,New York),(2,Washington),(3,Orlando),(4,Syracuse),(5,Buffalo)

Comment: *They both reference a table Prison with columns* on which exact columns is this join done ?

Comment: So the result I would want based on those examples would be:
(New York, Orlando), (Washington, Syracuse), (Buffalo, New York).

Comment: you mean  `TransferRequest` references `Prison` on `Prison.ID=TransferRequest.ID` ?

Comment: but its not the TransferRequest.id, it's the TransferRequest.receivingPrison and the TransferRequest.currentPrison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but if you just want to get the location names for the current and receiving prisons you could get them by joining the`prison`table twice:

```
SELECT 
  rec_prison.location as 'Recieving Location',
  cur_prison.location as 'Current Location'
FROM TransferRequest tr
INNER JOIN Prison rec_prison 
  ON rec_prison.prisonID = tr.receivingPrison 
INNER JOIN Prison cur_prison 
  ON cur_prison.prisonID = tr.currentPrison;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7ca68/2)

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery could do it:

```
SELECT P1.location AS location1

, (SELECT Prison.location  
FROM Prison
JOIN TransferRequest
ON Prison.prisonID = TransferRequest.receivingPrison ) AS location2

FROM Prison P1
JOIN TransferRequest T1
   ON P1.prisonID = T1.currentPrison;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT (SELECT       prison.Location
        FROM         TransferRequest tr
        INNER JOIN   Prison prison ON tr.reciveingPrisonID = prison.prisonID
        WHERE        tr.reciveingPrisonID = 1) AS'Recieving Location',
       (SELECT       prison.Location
        FROM         TransferRequest tr
        INNER JOIN   Prison prison ON tr.currentPrisonID = prison.prisonID
        WHERE        tr.currentPrisonID = 4) as 'Current Location'
```

See this here-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aac5/9

Hope this helps!!!